# Automatically generate id on headings that are inserted by TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, tinymce, nokogiri

The default behaviour in TinyMCE is to create headings as such:

```
<h1>My heading text!</h1>
```

We're currently building a table of contents macro for our app which uses TinyMCE.  I'd like the generated headers to include a random ID so that we can easily link to them from our generated table of contents.

Is there a way that I'm not seeing to customise how TinyMCE generates the HTML for headings so that I can include an id for each one?

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up deciding to do this server side using Nokogiri.  The headings generated by TinyMCE are being iterated over by an xpath query, and I'm setting the id on them that way.

```
doc.xpath(%w(h1 h2 h3 h4 h6).map { |h| Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for("body #{h}") }.join("|")).each do |node|
  node['id'] = to_anchor(node.content)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Scratch what I previously said, it looks like this is what you want:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.addClass(tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select('h1'), 'myClass');
```

Forgive my unfamiliarity with tinyMCE, I'm not sure if you need to create/select an "active" editor prior to calling this (I would assume so), but I bet you can figure that part out :)